# how to detect when TileOverlay has completed downloading tiles?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using multiple TileOverlay objects as "frames" for my map animation.  When an TileOverlay is made visible (via TileOverlay.setVisible(true)), it will start downloading the tiles.  How can I detect when the tiles for the overlay have been downloaded and displayed?

Comment: Can you link to the docs you're referencing?

Comment: Are you referring to docs for Android Maps v2 API? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/package-summary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to know from the API if **all** visible `Tiles` are downloaded and displayed.

If you want to know when a single `Tile` is downloaded, you may put some code before `return` in `TileProvider.getTile`. This way you can count downloaded tiles and have some estimates on your original question.

Comment: Thanks.  This does provide the best indication of when the tiles are downloaded.  However, I do notice that even after getTile returns, the tiles may still be in the process of getting displayed, so there's a some time lag.

Comment: @Pedro, I see this lag also, and it has caused me to add some work-arounds since I need to know when the tiles are truly finished.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [OnMapLoadedCallback](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback)

```
mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLoaded() {
            //Your code
        }
    });
```