# Determine Google Map Tiles are Loaded

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I am showing a Google Map in my Android Activity which extends FragmentActivity.  The map is loaded from the xml layout as follows:

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_above="@+id/ad_layout"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

The user can perform certain functions on the map only if the map tiles have finished downloading.  Is there a way to determine if the map tiles have finished downloading and are visible - besides obviously looking at the map?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380546/how-to-detect-when-tileoverlay-has-completed-downloading-tiles

Comment: I disagree with the proposed duplicate.  This question is asking about if the base map tiles have been loaded.  The other question is asking about if an additional custom TileOverlay has been loaded.

Comment: I have not found a way to do this myself.  I'm fairly certain it is an API limitation and have opened a feature request with the maps team.  Please star it so that it gets more attention :) https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5779

Answer (score 1):

Set an onCameraChangeListener this will be fired off when the map has finished loading.  Do whatever you wish to do then remove the listener so that it only happens once.

map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {

            //TODO: move camera, do whatever you need to do etc...

            // remove listener so that position is not reset when user touches map
            map.setOnCameraChangeListener(null);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Add OnMapLoadedCallback Listener to your google map object in your activity/fragment

```
 googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapLoaded() {
                // perform certain functions();
            }
        });
```

For More Reference: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback